# why call back function is not working though i had write it

Tags: debugging, kivy, kivy-language

I am new at kivy , every time I tried self .button. bind(), and I had tried some on_ press = self. callback, but it does not work. I even tried like , putting on_click, state by reading the documentation of kivy . I also tried to look for stack overflow for similar error but I couldn't find any effective way. And it ache me .
here is my code

```
    '''

    from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
    from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
    from kivy.uix.label import Label
    from kivy.uix.button import Button
    from kivy.uix.image import Image
    from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
    
    class Kivy_ui(GridLayout):
        def __init__(self,**kwargs):
            super().__init__(**kwargs)
            self.rows= 2 #defining the rows
            self.cols = 3 #defininig the columns
            self.image = Image(
                source = 'background.jpg'
                )
            self.add_widget(self.image)
            self.label = Label(
                text = 'Enter your name'
                )
            self.add_widget(self.label)
            self.text_input = TextInput(
                text =''
                )
                self.add_widget(self.text_input)
                self.button = Button(
                text = 'submit'
                )
    
            self.button.bind(on_click=self.callback) #everytime if button is clicked it moved to call back
            self.add_widget(self.button)
#for poppup menu like display

            self.popup = Popup(
            title='Pop_UP display',
            size= (300,400)#size of window,
            content = Label(
                text='')
            )
            def callback(self, elem):# this function help to callback evertime, submitted button is pressed
    
                self.popup.content.text = self.text_input.text
                self.popup.open()
    class demoap(App): #demo app
        def build(self):
            return Kivy_ui()
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        demoap().run()
    '''

and the output comes as

    '''
     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "G:\project\game\kivy\kivy_ui.py", line 46, in <module>
         demoap().run()
       File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 949, in run
         self._run_prepare()
       File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 919, in _run_prepare
         root = self.build()
       File "G:\project\game\kivy\kivy_ui.py", line 44, in build
         return Kivy_ui()
       File "G:\project\game\kivy\kivy_ui.py", line 30, in __init__
         self.button.bind(on_click=self.callback)
     AttributeError: 'Kivy_ui' object has no attribute 'callback'
    
    '''
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with using clock.

Hope it might be helpful.

Have a great day..

````
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.clock import Clock
KV = '''
BoxLayout:
    Button:
        text: "hello world"
'''
class uiApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        print('IM Building here')
        self.callback_limit = 5 
        self.nbr_callback_made = 0
        self.screen = Builder.load_string(KV)
        self.event = Clock.schedule_interval(self.my_callback, 2)# 2 sec interval before it callback the method
    def my_callback(self, dt):
        if self.nbr_callback_made == self.callback_limit:
            self.event.cancel()
            return
        print('Inside callback',nbr_callback_made)
        self.nbr_callback_made += 1
uiApp().run()```
````

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error message `'Kivy_ui' object has no attribute 'callback'` because your definition of the `callback` is within the `__init__()` method, which means that there is no `self.callback`. Just un-indent the entire definition of `callback` so that it is not part of `__init__()`.